# I'm getting a MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException when trying to connect to "smtp.office365.com"

Tags: c#, email, ssl, mailkit

I am trying to use MailKit to send an email message via "smtp.office365.com".  Here is the code I'm using.

```cs
using (var client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("smtp.log")))
{
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
    client.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.Authenticate(new SaslMechanismNtlmIntegrated());
    Debug.WriteLine(client.IsAuthenticated);
    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

The `SaslMechanismNtlmIntegrated` class I got from [this comment](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/332#issuecomment-398300208) on GitHub.

Whenever I run this code, I get an `SslHandshakeException`.

Here are the details of the exception:

```
MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS.

The other possibility is that the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
2. The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.
3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.

See https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate for possible solutions.
  Source=MailKit
  StackTrace:
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.<ConnectAsync>d__70.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Connect(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at QuoteAndOrder.SpecialsQuoteWindow.BtnEmail_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in SpecialsQuoteWindow.xaml.cs:line 501

Inner Exception 1:
IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

I went to the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate) mentioned in the details, but the workaround given did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Try using `SecureSocketOptions.StartTls` instead of `SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect`

Comment: I've updated the FAQ to explain the different types of SSL connections since people keep getting confused about what options to use and when.

Comment: For anyone else out there getting this exception when using a legacy app targeting .NET Core 2.0, you can fix the problem by running the app on .NET Core 2.2.0 or later (e.g. by running `dotnet --fx-version 2.2.0 .\YourAppNameHere.dll`).

Answer (score 23):

The solution mentioned by [willaien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55287641/im-getting-a-mailkit-security-sslhandshakeexception-when-trying-to-connect-to?noredirect=1#comment97305179_55287641) resolved this issue.  Namely, using `SecureSocketOptions.StartTls` instead of `SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect`.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I had to use port 587 instead of 25 .

Comment: This gave me another exception: MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException: 'The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.'

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours debugging this exception and none of the reasons indicated in the MailKit's [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ssl-handshake-exception) have helped.

So I'm adding my 2 cents for future googlers who might experience this error and land here.

#### Background

For TLS/SSL stuff .NET somewhat uses operating system's cryptographic primitives (`SChannel` on Windows and `OpenSSL` on Linux). These libraries can be configured to use a set of "cihper suites" that are not supported by the remote server that you're trying to connect to.

Look closely at the inner-exception of the `SslHandShakeException`.

In my case I was getting a `"SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL"` error on Linux.

Assuming you can't just call the email server provider and ask them to upgrade their cipher suites, here's what you do:

#### Linux fix

To resolve this error on Linux you typically need to edit `/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf` file and lower the CipherString `SECLEVEL` from "2" to "1"

```
[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

#### Windows fix

On Windows the enabled/disabled cipher suites are controlled by the registry, you can google for the keys and values to change. Or try a free tool called "IISCrypto" that everyone uses as a GUI editor for this kind of stuff (I'm not affiliated with IISCrypto, but I did use it a lot back in my Windows days)